# pixel 3a how to fix washed out purple screen

Tags: google-pixel

I have a pixel 3a that has a purple washed out screen.  Poor contrast I can hardly see icons.  This is worse than just "red hue" it's weird.  I've tried rebooting, resetting phone.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a hardware issue.

With android 11 I was able to "mostly see" icons using an app called "screen filter".

Now with 12, that doesn't work, but by turning night light on (intensity full), extra dim on, and dark theme on, I can see OK.